# How to edit different parts of document side by side?

Tags: editors

I need to edit different parts of the document side by side. I cannot split the editor into two parts. I tried to run another instance of it, but it just goes back to the same existing one. I'm using TexMakerX

Comment: For example in [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) it is possible what you want. I guess starting different instances of TeXMakerX depends on your operating system. You may also have a look on diff tools like [meld](http://meldmerge.org/).

Answer (score 3):

TexMakerX is now called [TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/), maybe you want to update to the newest version. TeXstudio supports multiple instances, you just need to launch it from the command line using the command line option `--start-always`.
More options are described in the [user manual](http://texstudio.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/texstudio/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html), [section 4.10](http://texstudio.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/texstudio/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html#SECTION38)